# Acending conditional count (to Sessionize web traffic) in R

Tags: r

I'm looking to sessionise some web traffic. I have a column in my data frame which summarises the duration of time until the next request in seconds, it might look like this:

`TimeToNext <- c(0,526,274,3000,1, 1900)`

I figured I could write a snazzy little function that keeps a track of a session number within it and then adds a numeric session value which would go up by 1 (ie...new session) if the `TimeToNext` exceeds my threshold... something like:

`session_length <- 1800`

I tried writing the following (nb, thought i'd add in a session override, so i could choose to start at a higher number if needed, that's the `start_session`):

```
sessionise <- function(TimeToNext, start_session = 1) {
   session = start_session
   if(TimeToNext >= session_length) {
     session = session + 1
     session
   } else {
     session
   }
}
```

but this gets me the following warning:

> ```
> Warning message: 
> In if (TimeToNext >= session_length) { :   the
> condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> ```

I don't get it... I can do:

```
TimeToNext[1:6] > 1800
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

I figure i must be missing something on scope about setting a variable from within an conditional loop...

Just to be clear, on the above example what I'd be looking for would be something like:

```
sessionise(TimeToNext)
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3
```

Am i missing something about scope? or am I mishandling a data frame somehow..?

Comment: Shouldnt it be `1,1,1,2,2,2` ? i.e. `cumsum(TimeToNext > 1800)+1`

Comment: Quite right, that was a typo, have amended the top to `TimeToNext <- c(0,526,274,3000,1, 1900)`. Thanks!

Comment: `cusum` looks like just what I was after! put it in answer and I'll mark it correct. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` to create the function, i.e.

```
f1 <- function(TimeToNext, session_length, Startsession = 1){
  cumsum(TimeToNext > session_length) + Startsession
}

f1(TimeToNext = TimeToNext, session_length = 1800)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3
```